# coarse lines - Winforms, WPF, c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm writing a very simple draw on screen tool. When I have my thickness to a low value, it looks pretty smooth, but when I go to a larger size, the lines become super jagged (see below)

```
            Line line = new Line();
            Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 
            line.Stroke = brush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
            line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
            line.StrokeThickness = 40;
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            paintSurface.Children.Add(line);
```

see image at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVTqD.jpg (can't post yet, I'm new)

My original app is a WinForms app. I tried to redo it in WPF, hoping that it would be better, but the above is from the WPF app - exactly the same problem. Is there any way that I get a better looking line?

Code in WinForm:

```
 penDraw = new Pen(Color.Black, 20);
 using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
 {
      g.DrawLine(penDraw, pt, ptLast);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it, turns out you only need to set `StrokeStartLineCap` and `StrokeEndLineCap` properties of the `Line` to `PenLineCap.Round`, also make sure that you get the position relative to your sender and not your window

```
            var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
            Line line = new Line();
            line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            line.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
            line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = e.GetPosition(canvas).X;
            line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(canvas).Y;
            line.StrokeThickness = 40;
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            canvas.Children.Add(line);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I tried both of the suggestions - both don't change anything.

Comment: this is brilliant. Would love to upvote, but need more reputation first!

Do you know if something similar can be applied to WinForms?

Comment: @PaulGitter those properties exist for the Pen too so its almost the same

Comment: thank you again. big help.

just adding  penDraw.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                penDraw.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round; fixed everything.